# How can I generate all possible sorted arrays from alternate elements of two sorted arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I recently encountered this question in an interview. I wasn't really able to come up with an answer to this. I started with, take first element from first array, and then find how many elements are greater than this element in the other array. But then, I mean, I don't know, couldn't really form a solution. The problem is as follows:

Given two sorted arrays A and B, generate all possible arrays such that first element is taken from A then from B then from A and so on in increasing order till the arrays exhausted. The generated arrays should end with an element from B.

```
Eg:
A = {10, 15, 25}
B = {1, 5, 20, 30}

The resulting arrays are:
  10 20
  10 20 25 30
  10 30
  15 20
  15 20 25 30
  15 30
  25 30
```

I am not looking for a code, just an algo/pseduo-code would do fine. Thanks!

Comment: Always ask the interviewer to provide you with a suggested answer sheet afterwards.

Comment: What's a suggested answer sheet? :/

Comment: What they feel your answer should address. More than often the people can't even solve the problems they ask.

Comment: Oh! Right. I will keep this in mind from next time onwards for sure. Nice tip. Thanks! But, since I am just a beginner right now, won't this come out as offensive to the interviewer? Can't he/she just say, just answer the question asked. Just asking.

Comment: @john So first number should always be from 1st array?

Comment: It depends really. This is not a trivial question. Not too hard, but I would say quite hard for a beginner. If they refuse, tell them you would like to learn from possible mistakes, and have a benchmark to compare yourself with. If they find that offensive, I would find them offensive. (I have had interviews where they asked me to solve problems they did not have answers for. Some ended up requiring post graduate math experience... Something they would know I did not have if they looked at my CV and worked out the problem themselves.)

Comment: @karthik, yes first number always will be from first array.

Comment: @leppie, right. Though, there exists a wide variety of people each with their own different minds and one can never guess what might come out as offensive to others, but yes, the above sounds reasonable. Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: why are `{10,20,25}` and `{15,20,25}` not included in your example result?

Comment: @גלעד ברקן those two entries were not included in the result as the last element should always be from B (which does not have 25).

Comment: @SaiGudigundla thanks, i missed that.

Answer (score 5):

How about using a directed graph with a BFS search of paths.

1. Create a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) where a directed edge is created from an element in array A to every element in array B if that element in B is greater. And vice verse. A directed edge is created from an element in array B to every element in array A if that element in A is greater.
2. Pick an element from A
3. Then use a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) search to generate all possible paths.
4. Every time a path includes an element from B add that sub-path to your solution list of paths
5. Stop when all elements of A have been used as a search key

**Update**

Per suggestion by @MiljenMikic, you can exploit the fact that the arrays are sorted by speeding up Step 1. You don't have to search all elements in the other array to find greater-than elements. Just keep track of the last found and move the pointer forward as you search.

Answer (score 5):

BFS solution that @dpmcmlxxvi proposed is interesting. In addition, I would suggest a recursive variant. Some basic points:

- one of the input arguments of your recursive function should be a boolean variable that will indicate whether you should add an element from A or from B; you will alternate this value in subsequent recursive calls
- arrays are sorted - use that information! When you see sorted arrays, always think of *binary search* - in this case you should recursively pass last added element and then, in the other array, binary search for the first element that is greater than that last element
- if the last added element was from B, add the current working array to the resulting list

Comment: What is the time complexity of this solution? O(n*m) where n & m are lengths of the two arrays?

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesh Actually, in the worst case when elements are alternating (i.e. A[i] < B[i] < A[i+1] for every index) you will have (m + n) + (m-1 + n-1) + (m-2 + n-2) + ... = m(m+1) / 2 + n(n+1)/2 operations, which gives O(n^2+m^2) time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive simple java based solution can be like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] A = {10, 15, 25};
    int[] B = {1, 5, 20, 30};

    Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        st.push(A[i]);
        generateArrays(A, B, i, 0, st, false);
        st.clear();
    }
}

static void generateArrays(int ar1[], int ar2[], int index_of_a, int index_of_b, Stack<Integer> st, boolean first) {
    if (index_of_a >= ar1.length || index_of_b >= ar2.length) {
        st.pop();
        return;
    }

    // take from second if available
    if (!first) {
        for (int j = index_of_b; j < ar2.length; j++) {
            if (ar1[index_of_a] < ar2[j]) {
                st.push(ar2[j]);
                System.out.println(st);
                generateArrays(ar1, ar2, index_of_a + 1, j, st, true);
            }
        }
    }

    // take from first if available
    else if (first) {
        for (int i = index_of_a; i < ar1.length; i++) {
            if (ar1[i] > ar2[index_of_b]) {
                st.push(ar1[i]);
                generateArrays(ar1, ar2, i, index_of_a + 1, st, false);
            }
        }
    }

    st.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry am a bit lazy to write the algorithm, but you can drive it from the code. below this is my solution you may use it

```
void Generate_all_possible_sorted_arrays_from_two_sorted_arrays(int[] a1,int[] a2){
    int[] array3=new int[a1.length+a2.length];// max length
    int flag=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a2.length;j++){
            if(a1[i]<a2[j]){
                System.out.println(a1[i]+" "+a2[j]);
                flag+=2;
                array3[flag-1]=a1[i];
                array3[flag]=a2[j];
                int k=i+1,l=j+1;
                findWave:for(;k<a1.length;k++){
                    if(a1[k]>array3[flag]){
                        for(;l<a2.length;l++){
                            if(a2[l]>a1[k]){
                                flag+=2;
                                array3[flag-1]=a1[k];
                                array3[flag]=a2[l];
                                for(int element=0;element<=flag;element++){
                                    System.out.print(array3[element]+" ");
                                }
                                System.out.println();
                             continue findWave;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            flag=-1;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```