# generating all possible sorted arrays from alternating elements of two sorted arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was working on the following problem and didn't understand how it's getting all the resulting arrays after following the recursive solution provided as an answer to [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300306/how-can-i-generate-all-possible-sorted-arrays-from-alternate-elements-of-two-sor):

**The problem is:** Given two sorted arrays A and B, generate all possible arrays such that first element is taken from A then from B then from A and so on in increasing order till the arrays exhausted. The generated arrays should end with an element from B.

Example:
A = {10, 15, 25}
B = {1, 5, 20, 30}

The resulting arrays are:
[10 20] , [10 20 25 30], [10 30], [15 20], [15 20 25 30], [15 30], [25 30]
**Proposed solution:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] A = {10, 15, 25};
    int[] B = {1, 5, 20, 30};

    Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        st.push(A[i]);
        generateArrays(A, B, i, 0, st, false);
        st.clear();
    }
}

static void generateArrays(int ar1[], int ar2[], int index_of_a, int index_of_b, Stack<Integer> st, boolean first) {
    if (index_of_a >= ar1.length || index_of_b >= ar2.length) {
        st.pop();
        return;
    }

    // take from second if available
    if (!first) {
        for (int j = index_of_b; j < ar2.length; j++) {
            if (ar1[index_of_a] < ar2[j]) {
                st.push(ar2[j]);
                System.out.println(st);
                generateArrays(ar1, ar2, index_of_a + 1, j, st, true);
            }
        }
    }

    // take from first if available
    else if (first) {
        for (int i = index_of_a; i < ar1.length; i++) {
            if (ar1[i] > ar2[index_of_b]) {
                st.push(ar1[i]);
                generateArrays(ar1, ar2, i, index_of_b + 1, st, false);
            }
        }
    }

    st.pop();
}
```

After executing the algorithm with the given input example manually by myself, I didn't get [10 30], [15 30] figured in the resulting arrays.

So, I tried to understand by debugging the code and found that **index of a** and **index of b** are **decreasing** each time the for loops on i or j are not proceeded into, as well as the value of first which is changing value until we get index of a = 0 and index of b = 1. Why is that happening? what Am I missing in the flow of the algortihm execution? How does the algorithm get [10 30], [15 30] in the output?

Comment: I don't understand your question very well. Does [10, 30] and [15, 30] not appear in your array output?

Comment: I made some edits in my questions as I figured it's not clear. They appear but I don't understand how.

Comment: You could save the parameter `first` by simply switching parameters with each call, such that `a` becomes `b` and vice versa with each call and only accepting solutions with an even number of parameters. Would reduce the redundancy of the code quite a bit. E.g.: `generateArray(arr1, arr2, indexA, indexB, stack){ acceptIf(stack.size() % 2 == 0); ... generateArray(arr2, arr1, indexB, indexA, stack); ... }` as pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

Note that each call to generateArrays(), pops the stack (the stack is an object and therefore is the same in all method calls) and therefore makes it go back to its original state, so you can assume that after each iteration of the for loop, the stack was the same as it was before.

I.e. doing:

```
    st.push(ar1[i]);
    generateArrays(ar1, ar2, i, index_of_b + 1, st, false);
```

Will leave the stack unaffected.

The very first call:
`generateArrays(A, B, i, 0, st, false);`

generates 3 method calls from this loop:

```
    for (int i = index_of_a; i < ar1.length; i++) {
        if (ar1[i] > ar2[index_of_b]) {
            st.push(ar1[i]);
            generateArrays(ar1, ar2, i, index_of_b + 1, st, false);
        }
    }
```

With stack containing values [10], [15] and [25].

> [10,30]

When **stack is [10]** it goes to the prior loop and generates 2 calls:

```
    for (int j = index_of_b; j < ar2.length; j++) {
        if (ar1[index_of_a] < ar2[j]) {
            st.push(ar2[j]);
            System.out.println(st);
            generateArrays(ar1, ar2, index_of_a + 1, j, st, true);
        }
    }
```

With stack containing values [10, 20], [10, 30] and prints them out as you can see.

> [15,30]

When **stack is [15]** it goes to the prior loop and generates 2 calls:

```
    for (int j = index_of_b; j < ar2.length; j++) {
        if (ar1[index_of_a] < ar2[j]) {
            st.push(ar2[j]);
            System.out.println(st);
            generateArrays(ar1, ar2, index_of_a + 1, j, st, true);
        }
    }
```

With stack containing values [15, 20], [15, 30] and prints them out.

EDIT: To explain more why `generateArrays` always ends up with one more pop:

`generateArrays` will either pop immediately (the base case):

```
if (index_of_a >= ar1.length || index_of_b >= ar2.length) {
    st.pop();
    return;
}
```

or pop at the end:

```
st.pop();
```

All `push` + `generateArrays` will result in an +1 push and +1 pop (per argument above), leaving the stack unchanged.

Comment: why is the pop done after each loop? I mean the last line in code.

Comment: Added a better explanation on the EDIT.